# oracle insert from select

Tags: sql, oracle

**updated(bold letters)** :

```
employee (empid,ename,edept,edetails,sal,deskno)
```

I am trying the below mentioned query, but not able to achieve to make it correct please help me 
note: I am naive in oracle pl/sql, please dont mind if you take it as a simple thing in oracle pl/sql

```
INSERT INTO employee
SELECT Replace(e.empid, 'id_', 'new_id_')     AS empid,
       Replace(e.ename, 'name_', 'new_name_') AS ename
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.empid = 1;
```

kindly let me know, if one can achieve this or not(employee table has 6 columns overall)

Comment: i have searched on SO, but not able to find the same situation stuff

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What is the structure of `employee` and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks..error is ora -00936 : missing expression

Comment: Do you have the columns `new_id_` and `new_name_` in your table?

Comment: Can you post your table definition?

Comment: @jain007: Did you forget to put quotes around `new_id_` and `new_name_`?

Comment: yup Codo, you r right, just updated the question

Comment: i m not sure, if it makes a diff : yes, empid is primary key

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
INSERT INTO employee (empid, ename)
SELECT Replace(e.empid, 'id_', 'new_id_')     AS empid,
       Replace(e.ename, 'name_', 'new_name_') AS ename
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.empid = 1;
```

Note the explicit column names on the first line and the quotes for `new_id_` and `new_name_`. Without the explicit column names, Oracle expects a query returning 15 columns.

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't think this affects the _missing expression_ error. The error should have been _not enough values_.

Comment: Also, I think `new_id_` is a name of a variable and quoting it won't be the solution. Please, no offence